# How to render a text box instead of a select box when using model form set

Tags: django, django-forms

When I render my formset, one of the field renders as a select box because it is a foreign field in the model. Is there a way to change this to a text input? I want to populate that field by using Ajax auto complete. Adding a widget to the modelform is not working because the modelformset_factory takes a model and not a model form.

**EDIT**

My Model Form

```
class RecipeIngredientForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RecipeIngredient

        widgets = { 'ingredient' : TextInput(), }
```

I use it in my view

```
RecipeIngredientFormSet = modelformset_factory(RecipeIngredient, form=RecipeIngredientForm)
    objRecipeIngredients = RecipeIngredientFormSet()
```

**EDITED MODEL FORM**

```
class RecipeIngredientForm(ModelForm):
    ingredient2 = TextInput()
    class Meta:
        model = RecipeIngredient
```

I create the form set like this

```
RecipeIngredientFormSet = modelformset_factory(RecipeIngredient, form=RecipeIngredientForm)
    objRecipeIngredients = RecipeIngredientFormSet()
```

**QUESTION**

Do I have to use the formset in html? Can I just hard code the fields that get generated and using javascript I can create new fields and increment the "form-TOTAL-FORMS"? If I can then I do not have to worry about my model form.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like this is a bug http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13095.

How can I apply the patch?

Answer (score 5):

modelformset_factory does take a form. Here's the function signature from `django.forms.models`:

```
def modelformset_factory(
           model, form=ModelForm, formfield_callback=lambda f: f.formfield(),
           formset=BaseModelFormSet,
           extra=1, can_delete=False, can_order=False,
           max_num=0, fields=None, exclude=None):
```

If this isn't working for you, show some code and I'll try and see what is going wrong.

**Edit after various comments** As you point out, the widget argument is buggy when used in this way. So the solution is not to use it - it's a very recent addition in any case. Instead, define the field directly on the form:

```
class RecipeIngredientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ingredient = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.TextInput))
    class Meta:
        model = RecipeIngredient
```

Comment: I updated my code but I get an error which says "<lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widget'". I only pass two parameters to the function.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the reply. I am unable to render the field, I still see the model form field.